# Auto-adjustable side DIVs

Tags: html, css, autoresize

I'm having some trouble finding the way to create 3 DIVs side by side, where the middle DIV has a static size (let's say 900px), and the ones on the left and right side have auto-adjustable widths.

I need to do this in order to put backgrounds on the side DIVs, because the middle div already has a transparent background, so I cannot create a wrapper DIV for the middle one holding the other background. As you might imagine, you'll be able to see through the middle DIV's background.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What do you mean by *auto-adjustable*? The two external `<div />` should take the remaining side place and be the same width?

Comment: can you post some code or an example. You question is too abstract.

Comment: This would be kind of what I need. I do not think it's that abstract :S
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/266PG/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="side" style="float:right;width:50px;">side</div>
    <div class="side" style="float:left;width:50px;">side</div>
    <div class="middle" style="margin:0 50px;">content middle</div>

    <div style="clear:both; height: 40px;"></div>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="left">side</div>
        <div class="center">center</div>
        <div class="right">side</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.side, .middle {
    text-align: center;
}
.side {
    background: red;
}
.middle {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left, .center, .right {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}

.center {
    width: 500px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/266PG/)

Comment: Kind of... But the widths of the side DIVs must be auto-adjustable. They must have automatic width so they can go from width "0" to "whatever-size-the-window-has", keeping the middle DIV always in the center of the window.

Comment: Amazing! You're a genius! I just made a few adjustments to your code and now it works perfectly :) This is the final result:
`<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header-left"></div>
    <div id="header-middle"></div>
    <div id="header-right"></div>
</div>`

Comment: And the CSS:
`#header-container {
    display: table;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
#header-left, #header-right {
 background: url("images/sides-bg.png");
 width: 50%;
}
#header-left, #header-middle, #header-right {
 display: table-cell;
}
#header-middle {
 background: url("images/header-bg.png") center;
 width: 56.25em;
 height: 6.9375em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}`

Comment: Seems I have to dig a bit more on the "display:table;" and "display:table-cell;" thing, it seems to be quite useful :)

Thanks a lot for your help man!

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you need a website with 3 columns where the left one is the menu, the middle has the content and the right one has room for advertisement or additional information.

I would go for something like:

```
<div class="side" style="width:10%; float:left;">content</div>

<div class="middle" style="width:900px; float:left;">content middle</div> 

<div class="side" style="width:10%; float:left; clear:both; ">content</div>
```

Depending on size and placement use the side classes for the sidebars and the middle class for your main content.

Comment: But with that, if the window was only 960px wide, the left and right columns would then overlap the middle column. Also the `clear: both` would break the layout by forcing the column to wrap to the next line.

Comment: Yes, cchana's observation is quite accurate. But however, the side DIVs are not for menus or advertisements, I just want them to hold a background image for the sides of the middle DIV. They would have to be able to go from width "0" to "whatever-size-the-window-has".

Comment: @cchana Ahh yes you're absolutely right, I should've put in a bit more time and effort testing it.